# Asp.net digit grouping while typing

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In asp.net project,
I want to group digits while typing in a textbox.
Example: 
123456123456
123.456.123.456

My aim is not grouping ip adress. I want it to read numbers easily. eg : 12.000.152.156.123.156

How can i do this?

Comment: @seckin what are you grouping for? a **numeric** grouping (like Number, Currency, etc, using the current localization settings) a normal **string** or an **IP Address**?

Comment: My aim is not grouping ip adress. I want it to read numbers easily. eg : 12.000.152.156.123.156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: If you instead want to do that on serverside(don't tag javascript, people have spent a lot of time to provide you a clientside solution):

```cs
double number = 123456123456;
String numeric = String.Format("{0:#,0}", number); // "123.456.123.456"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

---

*added by [balexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28004/balexandre)*

and you can always add some simple validation

```cs
using System.Net;

IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(); 
if(IPAddress.TryParse(numeric, out ip))
    // you get a valid IP Address in the ip variable
else
    // IP Address not valid, go back and ask again...
```

---

If you want to add a thousand separator to a numeric string value you can use this function:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function groupDigit(strDigit, separator) {
        if (separator == null || separator.length == 0) separator = ".";
        strDigit += '';
        x = strDigit.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + separator + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;
    }
</script>
```

test:

```
alert(groupDigit("123456123456", ".")); // 123.456.123.456
```

Comment: just added server IP validation :)

Comment: @balexandre: I'm not sure why you think that OP wants to validate an IP. He just wants to add a point every three digits, that's why i thought that he wants a [thousand separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping) which is the _point_ in many countries(like here in Germany). Btw, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DecimalSeparator.svg) is an overview.

Comment: good point! I always assumed that was an IP Address :-/ - just asked the op what he want to group...

Comment: @seckin: So `alert(groupDigit("112312312", "."));` displays   `1.12312312` instead of `112.312.312`? It works for me!

Answer (score 2):

This is called **masking** and there are several ways to accomplish that.

if you're new to ASP.NET you might start ith the use of the

> [ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/)

and make use of their [Masked Edit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx)

if you're a fan of jQuery, you can easily use a mask plugin. There are several but here is a [**live example** in JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ivevim/edit#javascript,html) of using the:

> [Masked Input jQuery Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

if it's an IP Address, here is a [**live example** in JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ivevim/5/edit#javascript,html) of using the:

> [IP Address jQuery Plugin](http://mlntn.com/2009/12/30/jquery-ip-address-plugin/)

---

**from comments** I can see that you only want to group numeric number for better readability, for that you can check the [**live example in JsBin**](http://jsbin.com/apevag/edit) witch was made using:

> [Tim Schmelter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10497708/28004) code

Comment: Masking is not good for me. I don't want masking. I want just to seperate number per 3.

Comment: separate in the server code? you mention as a tag `javascript` so that's why I pointed out a javascript solution.

Comment: no, not server code. When i type 10000, masking show is it like this :
100.00_.___ 
But i want 10.000

Comment: `10.000` is not a valid IP Address :) for what you're saying , you would probably need something like Windows has when you need to add Ip Addresses, but you always need to press `.` to move to the next group, this behavior can also be created on javascript.

Comment: I have changed my example, you now have a full IP Address grouping example.

Comment: @seckin: Edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10497708/284240) to show you a serverside approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter he said he's not trying to have a server side code ... :( I'm kinda lost ...

Comment: @balexandre: Ah, i've read "no, server code" (read over _not_). I'm lost too since my `groupDigit` should do exactly what he's asking.

Comment: My aim is not grouping ip adress. I want it to read numbers easily. eg : 12.000.152.156.123.156

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Jquery plugin http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/how-to-mask-input-with-jquery/

the advantage of this is that it will show the user exactly what the format will look like